# How to retrieve from Maven repositories that require access credentials?

Tags: maven

I need to retrieve data from Maven repositories, that require access credentials.  I know these access credentials.

The company possessing these repositories suggests to set up a corporate Maven repository and then proxy their repositories.  This sounds somehow complicated for me.

Can I set up retrieval without modifying the corporate Maven directory, just from my local using known access credentials?

Comment: If you have no access that means you need to have those credentials otherwise you won't get access to them. So that sounds like a hacking try...

Comment: I have access credentials, I just do not want to use the corporate repository

Answer (score 2):

Did you try to define these repos in your settings.xml?

You define these repos as ["servers"](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Servers). There, you can define the credentials for these servers as well...

Comment: I saw this option for servers but did not try yet. I will

Comment: yes it is helpful.  But how can I specify several repositories/URLs, should I define every repository as a server and the attach a mirror?

Comment: yes you have to specify each repo as a server (each one may have different URL and different credentials). As for the miror - actually this is not a must.

Comment: I already upvoted your answer, but I can get results only for one repository so far

Comment: try to run maven with -X (debug mode) so you will see in which repos he searches.

Comment: @OhadR I have the same problem and adding it as  '<server>' doesn't solved it.

Comment: @Jofkos post your pom.xml with settings.xml (maybe in another thread/question) so me and others will try to help.

Comment: @OhadR Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35733227/, thank you for your help :)