# Password protected jenkins maven repository server - access from maven

Tags: maven, authentication, jenkins, repository

I've got a password protected jenkins server with the [Jenkins Maven Repository Server](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Maven+Repository+Server) plugin. My problem is, as it is password protected, i can't access the /plugin/repository/everything/ repo from within maven (`Could not transfer metadata <metadata> from/to <repo-name> (http://ci.mydomain.com/plugin/repository/everything/): Access denied to: <repo>/<identifier> , ReasonPhrase:Forbidden.`)

What i tried:
- [Putting the server credentials in the .m2/settings.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27025081)
- Basic auth: `http://<user>:<password>@ci.mydomain.com/<repo>`
- without any auth

none worked...

any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

My settings.xml:

```
<settings>
  <servers>
      <server>
        <id>test-ci</id>
        <username>jenkins</username>
        <password>password</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
</settings>
```

and my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>

    <groupId>com.mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>Artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>test-ci</id>
            <url>http://ci.mydomain.com/plugin/repository/everything/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mygroup</groupId>
            <artifactId>ProjectOnCi</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: @OhadR yes and no. I'm using the Maven Repository Jenkins Plugin, which provides the build artifacts in a maven repo. But as my jenkins is restricted, Maven is not able to access that repo.

Comment: not sure i understand the usage of jenkins-maven-repo-plugin: can't you reach out to the repostory directly? what happens in cases where you want to build the project outside of jenkins?

Comment: the username/password in server tag should be of the Maven repo, not Jenkin's

Comment: Yeah but the jenkins password protections also protects the repo paths.

Comment: so why do you need the kenkins-repo-plugin? in the "repository" tag, put the url of the maven-repo (so jenkins is not involved). will it help?

Comment: The problem is, the repo is provided by the jenkins plugin, so it runs over jenkins in any case. So what you are saying is that it is not possible and i've to go for an external repository server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105163/discussion-between-ohadr-and-jofkos).

Comment: Can you build your project outside of jenkins? do you have an internal repository in your company? how your local repo gets the artifacts? from MacenCentral or from Nexus/Artifactory? the "maven repo server plugin" exposes project builds as a maven repository so the artifacts can be picked up by downstream builds or other systems. this is what you need to do ??

Comment: @OhadR I though of using the Jenkins repo as internal repo but it looks like I can't get it working. So I think I'll have to set up a maven repository server... For now my local repo gets the artifact through downloading the source from git and building it

Answer (score 1):

Just struggled a few hours with this problem today and finally found an answer.

First of all, to use HTTP basic authentication, you need to supply user and **API Token** as password. You can find this token at "Manage Jenkins" -> "Manage Users" -> "Edit User" (Settings icon next to user) -> "Show API Token".

Secondly, Jenkins is using **preemptive authentication**, which means that there is no HTTP authentication negotiation but you need to immediately send the credentials in the first request. You can read about it here: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Authenticating+scripted+clients

To configure your Maven repository accordingly, make sure to use the following server configuration:

```
<server>
    <id>test-ci</id>
    <username>YOUR_USER</username>
    <password>YOUR_API_TOKEN</password>
    <configuration>
        <httpConfiguration>
            <all>
                <usePreemptive>true</usePreemptive>
            </all>
        </httpConfiguration>
    </configuration>
</server>
```

This should work. I hope I could help you :)

Answer (score -1):

You should note that [Jenkins Maven Repository Server](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Maven+Repository+Server) will not perform as Maven Repository, so if this is what you need (a Maven repo) - this Jenkins plugin will not help.

I suggest reading about [Maven Repos](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html); from what you write I think that an internal repository (e.g. [Nexus](http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/), [Artifactory](https://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/)) might be good. Maven by default downloads JARs from Maven Central, so you do not (and should not) have to download all sources and build them.

Comment: It does performs as a maven repo, that's its job, but it is password protected, as i said.

Comment: This plug-in exposes **project builds** as a maven repository

Comment: Under the hood, all a maven repo needs is the jar/artifact, a manifest, some versioning and URL to access it.
I have seen examples for those who want to avoid using the jenkins maven plugin but also happen to use github, use the gh-pages branch on any github repo and add the repository artifacts there, which gives publicly available guthub hosted maven repo, sometimes this is done on the source code repo itself to avoid hassle of creating 2 places for code and artifacts